# Adding SQS as Trigger to Lambda (through management console)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to add SQS as Trigger for the Lambda function through management console:

[image]

but every time i click on add trigger and try to save it i get the below error:

[image]

As far as I understand this error appears if the lambda and sqs are in 2 different regions. But they both are in same region "US-East-2". This is my first time trying to create Lambda Function, what am i doing wrong? I would really appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have just replicated the scenario and issue is happening when you try to refer the queue which does not exist. I created a queue and added as Trigger it worked fine but then I deleted my queue and tried adding the queue it gave me below error.

[image]

This is because the queue I'm referring to was not present as I deleted it and it didn't sync to Lambda. Lambda still referring to the same queue though it doesn't exist.

So create your queue and then try to add it as a trigger after refreshing the console. It will work.

Comment: I have already created the queue. when i try "aws sqs list-queues" i can see the queue.C:\>aws sqs list-queues
{
    "QueueUrls": [
        "https://us-east-2.queue.amazonaws.com/***/Data-Integration-LogQueue.fifo",

Comment: is the issue because it is FIFO?